# pkgdown some references showing 404 and image on readme doesn't show on home

Tags: r, github, github-pages, pkgdown

Three of my reference links go to 404. This is one of them https://meghapsimatrix.github.io/simhelpers/reference/calc_absolute.html
The other two are calc_relative_var and calc_rejection 
I changed the names of these functions last night. I am not sure why that is throwing this error.

I am also trying to add an image to the README file it shows up as a broken image icon. I used the following to include the image:

```
<img src="man/figures/workflow.png" />
```

Here is the repository: https://github.com/meghapsimatrix/simhelpers

Things work fine when I build the site but break down when deployed on github pages :(

Comment: any answers? I looked through you repo, but I didn't find a solution...